# Is there a universal or standard way of adding loading spinners in angular apps?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to add loading spinner everywhere in my app where some data is fetched or posted to the backend but I am currently puzzled as to where I should add the check to turn loading from true to false or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [register a `HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) which stores the loading state for each request to the backend. Create a component that shows the loading indication (using the interceptor) and put it into your root/app component.

There are many articles around this topic if you search the web for "angular loading indicator http", here is one: ["Loading indicator in an Angular application"](https://marco.dev/angular-loading-indicator).

You can also use a library for that - I think [ngx-loading-bar](https://github.com/aitboudad/ngx-loading-bar) is the most popular for this use case.